# ¿Cómo hacer que un programa en python imprima los datos en un archivo .txt al arrancar la Raspberry?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, txt, print

Estoy haciendo un programa que al encender la Raspberry en Python3.7, se inicia.

La cuestión es que necesito que los datos que imprimo (print()) se guarden en un .txt. Hasta ahora he conseguido que el programa se inicie al encender la Raspberry con este código: `sudo python /home/pi/Carpeta/Programa.py` escrito al final de *autostart*. También he conseguido guardar los datos print() en un .txt poniendo este código directamente en el LXTerminal: `sudo python /home/pi/Carpeta/Programa.py > /home/pi/Carpeta/Guardado.txt`. Pero el problema es que no consigo que se guarde utilizando ese mismo código en el autostart.

También he intentado hacerlo con este códigos que he encontrado en un foro: `print("X", file=open("Guardado.txt", "a"))`, pero sólo me funciona desde el prograa de Python como tal. Ni al utilizarlo desde la terminal LX ni al reiniciar la Raspberry y que se ejecute el *autostart*.

Así que, la inicialización del programa al encender la Raspberry y el guardar los print() en un .txt funcionan pero por separado, pero no conjuntamente...

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias :)

Comment: Hay muchas formas de lograrlo, creo que lo más simple es intentar con crontab, y en la marca de tiempo usar @reboot.  Aquí una referencia https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/auto-run-python-programs-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Buenas! Muchas gracias. Lamentablemente sigue sin funcionar... No sé si tenga algo que ver que uso tkinter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

después de buscar y probar bastante, he encontrado una forma en la que funciona como quería, aunque tal vez haya una manera mejor o más fácil. Igualmente, por si a alguien le interesa, lo que he hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

Al inicio del programa poner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

Para que la Rasperry inicie el programa al encenderse, escribir en el LXTerminal:

```
cd /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
sudo nano autotart
```

Y al final de ese documento (*Autostart*), escribí lo siguiente
(es importante que si al inicio de tu programa escribes python3 aquí también o si escribes simplemente python, aquí también):

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/Carpeta/Programa.py
```

Y para el Print(), extraje de este enlace "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571560/directing-print-output-to-a-txt-file" lo siguiente:

```
Print('Lo que deseo imprimir', file=open('/home/pi/Carpeta/Guardado.txt','a'))
```

Espero que a alguien le sea útil.